# Firing a CustomEvent into an IHTMLDocument instance from C++

Tags: c++, qt, dom-events, ihtmldocument

I have a Qt 3.3 application that instantiates a WebBrowser control and I need to fire a CustomEvent at the current document with a JSON string as the detail property.

A similar question has been asked before but the answer uses deprecated APIs (e.g. `createEventObject`).  What is the currently recommended approach?  I am having great difficulty finding any documentation online and the procedure seems to be quite complex to achieve a simple result.

Comment: *"Currently recommended approach"* and *"Qt 3.3"* do not go together.

Comment: Are you serious that you have a Qt 3.3. application?

Comment: Yes. It isn't an option to change it when you have a very large historical code base (not that it is my decision in any case.)